# Error during try to edit object

Tags: pimcore

I create the objects in pimcore DB from the mySQL procedure.

I put data to objects, object_query_id, object_store_id, and my table.

After it I can see al objects correct, but if I try to edit one of them I had an error:

```
~invalid key for object with id [ 30553 ] key is: [2015_11_21_9_45_RT_D_EC_DME_RMI_oid_28748_did_28739_YYYYMMDDHH_2015112017]~
```

This key is unique, I sure. What it's mean?

Thanks at all.

This is my query for insert objects into tables (I use own view):

```
INSERT INTO bd_avia.objects
( o_parentId ,o_type ,o_key ,o_path ,o_index ,o_published ,o_creationDate ,o_modificationDate ,o_userOwner ,o_userModification ,o_classId ,o_className)
(SELECT
  15378 o_parentId,  'object' o_type,  t.o_key,  '/airticket/' o_path,  8888 o_index,  0 o_published,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() o_creationDate,  
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() o_modificationDate,  2 o_userOwner,  4 o_userModification,  6 oo_classId,  'airticket' oo_className
FROM bd_avia.generateRT t);

INSERT INTO bd_avia.object_query_6
(
  oo_id ,oo_classId ,oo_className ,type_way 
 ,ow_ticket_type ,ow_origincode ,ow_destinationcode ,ow_depart ,ow_arrive ,ow_flightnumber ,ow_airlinecode ,ow_duration 
 ,bk_ticket_type ,bk_origincode ,bk_destinationcode ,bk_depart ,bk_arrive ,bk_flightnumber ,bk_airlinecode ,bk_duration 
 ,currencycode ,totaladultprice ,totalchildprice ,totalinfantprice ,flightdescription ,flightnote ,quantity ,state ,nettoadultprice ,nettochildprice ,nettoinfantprice ,supplier
)
(
  SELECT
  o.o_id oo_id ,oo_classId ,oo_className ,type_way 
 ,ow_ticket_type ,ow_origincode ,ow_destinationcode ,ow_depart ,ow_arrive ,ow_flightnumber ,ow_airlinecode ,ow_duration 
 ,bk_ticket_type ,bk_origincode ,bk_destinationcode ,bk_depart ,bk_arrive ,bk_flightnumber ,bk_airlinecode ,bk_duration 
 ,currencycode ,totaladultprice ,totalchildprice ,totalinfantprice ,flightdescription ,flightnote ,quantity ,state ,nettoadultprice ,nettochildprice ,nettoinfantprice ,supplier
 from generateRT rt INNER JOIN objects o ON o.o_key = rt.o_key
);

INSERT INTO bd_avia.object_store_6
(
  oo_id ,type_way 
 ,ow_ticket_type ,ow_origincode ,ow_destinationcode ,ow_depart ,ow_arrive ,ow_flightnumber ,ow_airlinecode ,ow_duration 
 ,bk_ticket_type ,bk_origincode ,bk_destinationcode ,bk_depart ,bk_arrive ,bk_flightnumber ,bk_airlinecode ,bk_duration
 ,currencycode ,totaladultprice ,totalchildprice ,totalinfantprice ,flightdescription ,flightnote ,quantity ,state ,nettoadultprice ,nettochildprice ,nettoinfantprice ,supplier
)
(
  SELECT
  o.o_id oo_id ,type_way
 ,ow_ticket_type ,ow_origincode ,ow_destinationcode ,ow_depart ,ow_arrive ,ow_flightnumber ,ow_airlinecode ,ow_duration
 ,bk_ticket_type ,bk_origincode ,bk_destinationcode ,bk_depart ,bk_arrive ,bk_flightnumber ,bk_airlinecode ,bk_duration
 ,currencycode ,totaladultprice ,totalchildprice ,totalinfantprice ,flightdescription ,flightnote ,quantity ,state ,nettoadultprice ,nettochildprice ,nettoinfantprice ,supplier
 from generateRT rt INNER JOIN objects o ON o.o_key = rt.o_key
);

INSERT INTO bd_avia.vvk_org_dst ( oid ,did ,o_key, tuStamp ) ( SELECT oid ,did ,o_key, tuStamp FROM generateRT );

UPDATE bd_avia.objects SET o_index = 0 WHERE o_index = 8888;
```

Answer (score 3):

The key must conform to this regex: `/^[a-z0-9_~\.\-]+$/`

Your key has uppercase letters. Make them lowercase. Pimcore relies on object keys being lowercase.

See also: [\Pimcore\Tool::isValidKey()](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/master/pimcore/lib/Pimcore/Tool.php#L34) - this is the function that checks if the key is valid.